# How to detect, if a shared library symlink is necessary?

Tags: gnu-make

I have makefile shared by multiple projects, which links shared libraries. The sources -- and the library-names -- are set by each project's own `GNUmakefile`.

When the library-name (`${SO}`) contains the version (such as `libfoo.so.2`) I need to create a symlink:

```
 libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.2
```

What's the elegant way to remove the version-number in this example?

```
SO_LINK=$(???? ${SO})
...
ifneq(${SO_LINK},${SO})
      ln -sf ${SO} ${SO_LINK}
endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for pointers at the `suffix` and `basename` functions.

I added the following variation to my library-creation rule:

```
ifneq ($(suffix $@),so)
    ln -sf $@ $(basename $@)
endif
```

(This is, what I actually needed. Because it does not answer my *initial* question, I rephrased it.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `subst` to get the version and then use the `filter-out` or `subst` to subtract the version from the library-name. Also, you can extract the suffix `SUB=$(suffix $(VAR))`

```
VAR = libfoo.so.2
TTT=libfoo.so

TMPVAR := $(VAR)
SUB=$(subst $(TTT),, $(TMPVAR))
VAR = $(filter-out $(SUB) , $(TMPVAR))

all:
    @echo "VAR is: $(VAR)"
```

Comment: I think `basename` (not the same as the unix one) might be easier.

Comment: @kabanus from his example, it shows that the only change is the version.

Comment: Yup, but it's the suffix in this case. Basename removes just that.

Comment: @kabanus In this way, he can extract the suffix  using `$(suffix names…)`

Answer (score 1):

I would rephrase the problem not to check if last suffix is a digit, but rather if second to last suffix is `so`. Therefore I would use `$(basename)` to remove last suffix and update the condition to check this new name if it ends with `.so`, i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
SO = libfoo.so.2
SO_LINK = $(basename $(SO))

all:
        touch $(SO)
ifneq ($(filter %.so,$(SO_LINK)),)
        ln -sf $(SO) $(SO_LINK)
endif
```

Output:

```
$ make
touch libfoo.so.2
ln -sf libfoo.so.2 libfoo.so
```

It can handle libraries without number and other double extensions as well (note no `ln`):

```
$ make SO=foo.tar.gz
touch foo.tar.gz
$ make SO=libbar.so
touch libbar.so
```